# I'm trying to do the generic "show text" function for this long paragraph but I can't get it to toggle the text properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The hide class on the span simply contains display none.
I want the text to appear when they click the "show more..." anchor, then that same anchor should say "show less" when they click show less it should go back to show more and re-add the hide class. This way I can toggle the hide class and make the text disappear and re-apear. I already tried getting rid of the anchor tag and just clicking on the text but this still didn't work.

```
<p>System three focuses on Hypertrophy.  More reps and Sets and More Exercises Per Muscle Groups. The goal for this System is to increase size and muscle mass
                     without the need of dangerously ego lifting. This is the hardest system yet the most useful because it teaches how to lift safely 
                     <span class="hide text-to-show">but effectively with intensity  that can be used for life. Must be consistent and confident in System one and Two to proceed to this Section </span><br>
                     <a href=""><span class="read-more-text">...</span></a></p>



 <script> let readMoreText = $(".read-more-text");
    const text = $('.text-to-show');
    
    $(readMoreText).click(()=>{
        text.classList.toggle('hide');
        if(readMoreText.innerText === 'show more...'){
            readMoreText.innerText = 'show less';
        }else{
            readMoreText.innerText = 'show more...';
        }
    })</script>
```

Comment: Change let to var

Comment: readMoreText is not accessible in the click handler with let.

Comment: I don't see why that would work, but I tried changing it and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! when you use JQuery to select an item by class it actually brings back an array of everything with that class. Even though this is the only element with this class, it is still in an array by itself in position 0 (as JS is zero-based). So the zero specifies its position in the array as 0 when the variable is called. I advise you to use IDs as much as possible if you are only targeting a specific element. The only thing I changed is I added the two Zeros.

```
let readMoreText = $(".read-more-text")[0];
const text = $('.text-to-show')[0];

$(readMoreText).click(()=>{
    console.log("function activated")
    text.classList.toggle('hide');
    if(readMoreText.innerText === 'show more...'){
        readMoreText.innerText = 'show less';
        alert("Hi");
    }else{
        readMoreText.innerText = 'show more...';
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

- `.text-to-show` can be referenced from inside the function
- `toggleClass` used instead of `classList`

```js
const readMoreText = $(".read-more-text");
$(readMoreText).click((e) => {
  $(".text-to-show").toggleClass("hide");
  if (e.currentTarget.innerText === "show more") {
    e.currentTarget.innerText = "show less";
  } else {
    e.currentTarget.innerText = "show more";
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>System three focuses on Hypertrophy. More reps and Sets and More Exercises Per Muscle Groups. The goal for this System is to increase size and muscle mass
  without the need of dangerously ego lifting. This is the hardest system yet the most useful because it teaches how to lift safely
  <span class="hide text-to-show">but effectively with intensity that can be used for life. Must be consistent and confident in System one and Two to proceed to this Section </span>
  <a href=""><span class="read-more-text">show more</span></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also found another way to do this please check out my answer below.

Comment: I see that .toggleClass would've been easier, but why use .on instead of click? This answer was helpful I upvoted it accordingly.

Comment: But `classList` & `toggle` are javascript functions. Thought you might want to use JQuery only.

Comment: Is on JQuery? I thought click was also Jquery?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I wanted to use event target object inside function instead of referring the element by class. But event reference is available in `.click()` also. Yes both `.on` & `.click` are available in jQuery. I will edit my answer.

Comment: We are learning!!! It's what StackOverflow is all about, yay!

Comment: Be aware that `$(".text-to-show").toggleClass("hide");` will always be applied on _all_ elements with class `text-to-show`. This might not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Or something like this:

```js
$(".read-more-text").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().prev().toggleClass("hide");
  this.innerText= this.innerText==="show more"?"show less":"show more";
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>System three focuses on Hypertrophy. More reps and Sets and More Exercises Per Muscle Groups. The goal for this System is to increase size and muscle mass
  without the need of dangerously ego lifting. This is the hardest system yet the most useful because it teaches how to lift safely
  <span class="hide text-to-show">but effectively with intensity that can be used for life. Must be consistent and confident in System one and Two to proceed to this Section </span>
  <a href=""><span class="read-more-text">show more</span></a>
</p>
<p>System four focuses on something else. It will descibred here in detail 
  <span class="hide text-to-show">but only after you clicked on the "show more" link.</span>
  <a href=""><span class="read-more-text">show more</span></a>
</p>
```